# HTML removes wanted spaces in between text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a question quite opposite to the questions already asked here. Let me just start off with the example.

When I go to **rails console** and type `Stock.where(item_code: "1234").pluck(:description)`

I get the following:

`(4.5ms)  SELECT "stocks"."description" FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."item_code" = ?  [["item_code", "1234"]] => ["R  Bag1234", "R  Bag1234"]`

As you can see there are clearly ***2 spaces*** in the **description**

`R  Bag1234`

But when I print this in my view using a loop, one space is removed. i.e. the description is

`R Bag1234`

**And I do not want any spaces to be removed.** Please advice what to do lol. Thanks!

> Here's a snippet of the view (index.html.erb)

```html
<% @stocks.each do |stock| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= stock.item_code %></td>
          <td><%= stock.description %></td>
          <td><%= stock.item_unit %></td>
          <td><%= stock.stock %></td>
        <tr>
<% end %>
```

> Here's a snippet of the controller (stocks_controller.rb)

```rb
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_stock, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /stocks or /stocks.json
  def index
    @stocks = Stock.all
  end
```

> And my schema.rb looks like this

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_12_23_215326) do

  create_table "stocks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "item_code"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "item_unit"
    t.decimal "stock"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

Ah also, I am using ruby 3.0.0 and rails 6.1.4 on windows 10

EDIT:

After a helpful comment, seems like it is an issue with HTML and nothing much to do with RoR. For Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ugvkqsn2/ the code in the above example shows 2 spaces with pure html but the browser only shows 1 space.

Comment: How do you know that there is only one space? Have you examined the HTML source that gets sent to the browser?

Comment: Oh interesting! The source code of the .html page does seem to have 2 white spaces but if we view it from the browser, there is only 1 space! Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/ugvkqsn2/ Seems to be an issue with html? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: FYI: [How whitespace is handled by HTML, CSS, and in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property to `pre` on the `<td>` elements where you don't want the whitespace to collapse like this:

```
<% @stocks.each do |stock| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= stock.item_code %></td>
      <td style="white-space: pre;"><%= stock.description %></td>
      <td><%= stock.item_unit %></td>
      <td><%= stock.stock %></td>
    <tr>
<% end %>
```